# Factory girl after(:create) unless parameter supplied.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have two models in my database. Users and Accounts. Every user belongs to an account and an account can have multiple users.

**Accounts.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    id { SecureRandom.uuid }

    after(:create) do |account|
      if account.users.empty?
        account.add_member!(create(:user))
      end
    end  
  end
end
```

**Users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    transient do
      name nil
      email nil
    end

    id { SecureRandom.uuid }
  end
end
```

At the moment, creating an account via `FactoryGirl.create(:account)` automatically creates a user on that account. The issue I am having at the moment is that I need `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` to also create an account for this new user. I tried just adding `account { FactoryGirl.create(:account) }` to the users factory but that created an infinite loop.

I am aware that I can use traits to specify a `:with_user` and `:with_account` for Accounts & Users respectively. The thing is that I want the default to be creating the necessary data. So in other words:

- `u = FactoryGirl.create(:user)` would create a user `u` that would also have an account that is accessible via `u.account` (this association is already setup).
- `a = FactoryGirl.create(:account)` would create an account `a` with a user that is accessible via `a.users.first` (also already setup).

I do NOT want to have to do `.create(:user, :with_account)` or `.create(:account, :with_user)`.

Is there a way to do a `:without_user` and `:without_account` that would bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. Having a pair of factories each of which creates an instance of the other by default feels like broken logic.

You might check out `FactoryGirl`'s `association` keyword if you haven't already - you could probably shorten your `Account` factory to:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    id { SecureRandom.uuid }
    association :user, factory: :user
  end
end
```